# Exporting UV layout with modifiers applied

Tags: uv, modifiers, image

I'm trying to export an UV layout with subdivision surface modifier on to paint it in photoshop, but I'm failing to do so. Whenever I export it it gives me my lowpoly model UV map

Comment: Hello. Did you really click the Apply button?

Comment: The problem is I'd rather not apply it now, is this possible?

Comment: @FFeller had the perfect solution: Check the Modified box as you're saving the layout. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159257/export-uv-layout-without-applying-modifiers?noredirect=1#comment269906_159257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the SubDivisionModifier to get the correct polycount and UV layout first, then export to Photoshop.

if you would like to work with the lowpoly without applying, I would make a copy of the original object, apply the modifier on the copy to get the correct SupDiv UVs and then use the texture on the original object.