# Export UV layout without applying modifiers?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, export, texture-painting

I have a mesh of a fortune cookie that has some modifiers on it.

I want to edit its image texture in Photoshop, and I want to work with the smooth UV layout that I can see while in Texture Paint mode:

[image: High-resolution UV layout of a fortune cookie in Texture Paint mode]

**How can I export that smooth UV layout? If Blender can render it onscreen, surely there must be a way to access the file.**

I'd rather not do these:

- Taking a screenshot. This is what I'm doing now.
- Applying modifiers first. I might want to change them later.
- Saving the image. I just get a black square.
- `Export UV layout`. Only the low-resolution UV map is exported:

[image: UV map with no modifiers]

Comment: In the "Export UV layout" window check in "modified".

Comment: In case others were confused, you can find the Modified box not in the editor panels but in the lower left of the dialog box that comes up after you do `Export UV layout`. Thanks so much, @FFeller!